# How can one change the download permissions of several videos at once in OneDrive?

Tags: office-365, onedrive

I have 10 videos on my OneDrive account (as part of my employer's Office 365 account) that are view-only by people having a link to it. How can I change their permissions at once so that all 10 videos can be downloaded by people having a link to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not possible to change the download permissions of several videos at once in OneDrive, as Reddit user  [ccatlett1984](https://www.reddit.com/user/ccatlett1984)  [stated](https://redd.it/p50awg):

> You can't, there really isn't a way to do that on the IT-side of things either.